LIMIT with GROUP in SPARQL
Say, that I, with the Wikidata Query Service, would like to sample 10 lexemes for each language. Would that be possible in SPARQL?
This would just give me 10 lexemes in any language:
SELECT ?lexeme ?language
WHERE { ?lexeme dct:language ?language . }
LIMIT 10

This would give me one lexeme for each language:
SELECT (SAMPLE(?lexeme) AS ?example_lexeme) ?language
WHERE { ?lexeme dct:language ?language . }
GROUP BY ?language
LIMIT 10

It would be something like (abusing SPARQL):
SELECT ?lexeme ?language
WHERE { ?lexeme dct:language ?language . }
LIMIT 10 PER ?language


I now see there is a related question: Select top X results per group

what you are asking for is a feature also called correlated subqueries or lateral join often in the SQL world. Currently, SPARQL 1.1 has no such feature, but it will be most likely in SPARQL 1.2 via LATERAL keyword, see https://github.com/w3c/sparql-dev/issues/100 . So far, it's not possible with a single standard SPARQL 1.1 query, some triple stores might already implement such an extension, e.g. Apache Jena (LATERAL) and Stardog
